# creating os x file directory with text edit and terminal

Tags: python

The following:

```
python -c 'import sys,os,codecs;[os.mkdir(d) for d in codecs.open(sys.argv[1],"r","utf8")]' testfolders.txt
```

create a "?" at the end of every file name

Is there a way to remove the ? or a better way of creating the folders than the above

Comment: Where did `testfolders.txt` come from, and what *exactly* is in it?

Comment: @chepner I created a list of folder names in a text edit document titled testfolders.txt

Comment: That doesn't tell me *exactly* what is in the file. `hexdump -C testfolders.txt` would.

Comment: `os.mkdir(d.strip())` - the lines you read from the file have newlines at the end.

Comment: List of Folder Names: Test Name & Test Name, Test Name @ Test Name, Test Name

Comment: Thanks @Jasonharper!